# subclassing from a Struct vs. using attr_accessible

Tags: ruby

In Ruby 1.8.6, I could write `class PerformableMethod < Struct.new(:object, :method, :args)`

Now in Ruby 1.9.3, that throws an error: `superclass mismatch for class PerformableMethod`

It works if I change the code to:

```
class PerformableMethod
    attr_accessor :object, :method_name, :args
```

But why doesn't the struct work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class name is optional also in 1.9 and 2.0. The problem is this:

```
> Struct.new(:asdf, :qwer) == Struct.new(:asdf, :qwer)
 => false
```

Even if you provide a class name for your `Struct`:

```
> Struct.new("Zxcv", :asdf, :qwer) == Struct.new("Zxcv", :asdf, :qwer)
(irb):22: warning: redefining constant Struct::Zxcv
 => false
```

This means that if you have this in a file that you load or require:

```
class MyClass < Struct.new(:qwer, :asdf)
  def some_method
    puts "blah"
  end
end
```

... then if you load it again -- maybe because you changed something and you want to try it without restarting irb, or maybe you are running Rails in dev mode and it reloads classes on each request -- then you get the exception:

```
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class MyClass
```

... because every time your class definition runs, it is declaring a brand new `Struct` as the superclass of `MyClass`. Providing a class name to `Struct.new()` does not help, as seen in the second code block; That just adds a warning about redefining a constant, and then opening the class fails anyway.

The only way to avoid the exception is to stash your `Struct` in a constant somewhere you control and make sure not to change that constant when the file is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

While typing out this question, my colleague sitting right next to me figured it out.

[Struct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html) now takes the class name as its first parameter.

So in Ruby 1.9.3 the following works:

```
class << Struct.new('PerformableMethod', :object, :method, :args)
```

Comment: That opens the singleton class for the `Struct`. It's not the same statement as the one in the question.